# How to log ajax request failures in rails application methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-log

I have rails 2 application full of ajax requested functionality.
I want to log the ajax request failure in log file as we can do in cron methods using begin rescue block.
Is there any way to log the ajax failure request with the method name?

Comment: Failed Ajax Request are already logged in the log file but if you want to show something in views when it fails you can use `:failure => "alert('HTTP Error ' + request.status + '!')"`  Ref:- http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002166

Answer (score 3):

All requests to the server (including ajax requests) should be logged in the log file.  Check your log file again, it should have entries for ajax requests as well.